# Solving Summation Expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, computational-complexity

I would like to know how do you solve summation expressions in an easy way (from my understanding).
I am computer science student analyzing for loops and finding it's time complexity.

e.g

**Code**:

```
 for i=1 to n
      x++
 end for
```

**Summation**:

```
  n  
  ∑ 1
 i=1
```

**Solving**:

```
 = ∑ [n-1+1]     (topLimit - bottomLimit + 1)
 = n             (summation formula said ∑ 1 = 1+1+1+1+ ... + 1 = n)
```

The time complexity of the for loop is: O(n)

---

**Code**

```
for(i=0; i<=n i++)
    for(j=i; j<=n; j++)
        x++;
```

**Question**:

How do you solve:

```
   n    n
   ∑   [∑ 1]
  i=1  j=i
```

**My Solution**:

```
   n
=  ∑  [n-i+1]
  i=1
= not sure how to progress from here (should i do another topLimit - bottomLimit + [n-i+1]?)
```

The problem i am having is simplifying so i can get to say i, 1/i, i^2, .. i.e something i can use a summation formula on.
I know the answer supposed to be: (n(n+1))/2.

Comment: it might help if you put in the code for your second example as well. I think it's a nested loop, but it isn't clear to me.

Comment: It is a nested loop, `for(i=0; i<=n i++) for(j=i; j<=n; j++) x++;`

Comment: You might get other answers, oriented towards compsci / software engineering, by searching / posting on stackoverflow. See, e.g., [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm).

Comment: Thanks @TooTone! I posted it here because i have problems with the Math part though.

Comment: cool, by the way with your second example a nice shortcut is to see the second loop as taking $½(n+1)$ on average, and as the first loop runs $n$ times you can simply take $n \times ½(n+1) = ½n(n+1) = \rm{O}(n^2)$. (Or, another way is to use [known formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) directly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly got down to this sum:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i+1)
$$
Now use the fact that finite sums are just additions, so you can use all the algebra rules you're used to and write it as
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n ((n+1)-i) &= \sum_{i=1}^n(n+1)-\sum_{i=1}^n i\\
&=(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n 1-\sum_{i=1}^n i
\end{align}
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Taking from there: `= (n+1)(n) - n(n+1)/2`, simplifying we get, `= n^2 + n - (n^2)/2 - n/2`, `= (n^2)/2 + n/2`, Answer: `= (n(n+1))/2`. Thanks lots for this :). My problem was breaking them up at that point.

Comment: No problem i was about to accept.. vote it up i need 15 rep :). One more question, notice how you split up the last summation into two, can i do this for 3 summations?
e.g `limits(k=1 to n)∑ (limits(i=1 to n) ∑ (limits j=i to n) ∑ 1))` , do we work on two at a time? then the answer from previous calculation would be used for the last summation?

Comment: @RyanHiga. There's no problem doing this same sort of thing for three or more summations. Just work from the innermost outward, as you did with your original problem. Of course, things get a bit messier, but it's certainly doable.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking up the sum into separate summations:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(n+1-i) = \sum_{i=1}^nn + \sum_{i=1}^n1 - \sum_{i=1}^ni
$$

Note the various summations rules, tricks, and simplifications for each of the summations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me how to split it up. From there i can do: 
`= (n)(n) + (n) - 1/2 n(n+1)`, 
`= n^2 + n - ([n^2]/2) - n/2`,
`= ([n^2]/2) + n/2`,
`= (n[n+1])/2`